# Occasional 'EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back' errors hanging the application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans, jboss6.x

Application is hosted in JBoss6 (version 6.0.0.Final).

In production environment I see sometimes the following errors:

```
2012-10-01 17:59:00,290 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-9) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:87) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) [:1.0.1]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:272) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.invokeEndpoint(StatelessContainer.java:617) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:137) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.AbstractInvoker._invokeInternal(AbstractInvoker.java:164) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:112) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [:2.3.1]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_23]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461) [:2.3.1]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.invoke(ServletControllerExt.java:172) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:57) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:156) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFNonSpringServletExt.invoke(CXFNonSpringServletExt.java:90) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103) [:2.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159) [:2.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:893) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2019) [:6.0.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16063 The transaction is not active!
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1148) [:6.0.0.Final]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.0.0.Final]
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:82) [:0.0.1]
... 65 more
```

It happens occasionally about once a week, and number of such exceptions is raising next minutes after first occasion, making entire application hang. After appserver restart, application works normally.

Until restart, there are 242 same errors in the log:

```
Line 18231: 2012-10-01 17:19:24,290 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-12) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 18404: 2012-10-01 17:19:34,009 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-3) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 18559: 2012-10-01 17:19:24,728 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-7) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 19222: 2012-10-01 17:20:14,728 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-11) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 20212: 2012-10-01 17:27:22,900 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-14) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 20606: 2012-10-01 17:27:32,853 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-16) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 21258: 2012-10-01 17:28:18,540 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-21) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 21361: 2012-10-01 17:28:39,353 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-17) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 21618: 2012-10-01 17:28:39,743 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-12) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 21693: 2012-10-01 17:28:39,884 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-10) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 22428: 2012-10-01 17:38:20,509 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-2) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 23606: 2012-10-01 17:38:51,790 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-35) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 23987: 2012-10-01 17:38:42,181 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-11) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 24378: 2012-10-01 17:39:02,259 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-14) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 24625: 2012-10-01 17:39:12,306 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-50) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 25032: 2012-10-01 17:39:24,947 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-17) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 25191: 2012-10-01 17:39:34,634 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-25) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 25610: 2012-10-01 17:39:34,853 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-40) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 25690: 2012-10-01 17:39:35,009 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-23) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 25932: 2012-10-01 17:39:35,165 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-35) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 26013: 2012-10-01 17:39:45,165 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-49) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 26170: 2012-10-01 17:39:45,243 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-42) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 26331: 2012-10-01 17:39:56,712 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-14) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
Line 26651: 2012-10-01 17:40:08,243 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-18) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
....other hundreds of errors...
Line 64132: 2012-10-01 18:19:01,712 ERROR [org.jboss.webservices.integration.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-444-15) Method invocation failed with exception: Transaction rolled back: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
```

Before each error there are the following entries in the log:

```
Line 18188: 2012-10-01 17:17:38,837 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA-12117 TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff505fe095:1274:505afcea:577d43 in state  RUN
Line 18189: 2012-10-01 17:17:38,868 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA-12095 Abort of action id 0:ffff505fe095:1274:505afcea:577d43 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
Line 18190: 2012-10-01 17:17:38,868 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA-12108 CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff505fe095:1274:505afcea:577d43 aborting with 1 threads active!
Line 18191: 2012-10-01 17:17:59,087 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA-12117 TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff505fe095:1274:505afcea:577d43 in state  CANCEL
Line 18229: 2012-10-01 17:19:24,290 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-ntpen1.company.name%2F80.95.224.149-81-12) ARJUNA-12077 Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff505fe095:1274:505afcea:577d43
```

Application itself is set of SOAP web-services and dynamic JSF/Richfaces web pages.
Most of the logic is located in stateless beans (@Stateless).

My guess is that sometimes calls to web-service take too much time, causing EJBTransactionRolledbackException. The question is why sometimes it hangs entire application? Plus the exception stacktrace doesn't contain calls in application code.

Can it be because of running out of pool (stateless bean objects pool)?

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual code this is just a guess, but this might be an effect of the bug [EJBTHREE-2238](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-2238) which exists in JBoss 6.0.0 final.